# Android Change Spinner theme/style with bottom border

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-theme

I have a spinner after i loaded data into it. the style is not as my expected.

Spinner code

```
<Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerGender"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

Current style.
[image]

My expected
[image]

How can i change theme/style the spinner

Answer (score 11):

try this,

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerGender"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

otherwise you can create custome style and use
Example at following link: 
http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-get-holo-spinner-theme-in-android-2-x/

Comment: @huynhthinh You should accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using the styles.xml file

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This works well, in-fact it also works when Spinner is created programmatically. Thanks!